# kibana tag cloud does not count frequency of words in a text field

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

kibana tag cloud does not count frequency of words in my  text field

let's say i have a field named : Ticket_text.keyword and here are some examples:

`hello world here I am`

`hello everybody this is blah`

`in this world`

I want my visualization to show "hello" as the most frequent and "world" as the second etc ...
but tag cloud treats my field as a whole not by individual words.
how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do that by updating my index mapping and setting field_data to true, here is my new mapping for "Ticket Text" field :

```
mapping = {
    "properties": {
        "Ticket Text": {
            "type": "text",
            "fielddata": True
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there's nothing to fix there; the tag clouds visualization in Kibana can only work over the entire keyword text